# Working with several RecyclerViews

Tags: java, android

In my android app, I've been using several RecyclerViews with the completely different look and requirements. As the number increased, I thought of unifying them. So my question is that for recyclerviews with different requirements, should I use different adapters (layout files can't be same) or one Universal Adapter like this:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < DataAdapter.ViewHolder > {
 variables...
 public DataAdapter(Context context) {

 }

 @Override
 public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
  //   if(the_condition_to check_which_recycler_view)
  //   inflate a;
  //   else if(other_condition)
  //   inflate b;
  //   else ...
  return xyz;
 }
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
  // if(the_condition_to check_which_recycler_view)
  //       do this;
  //       else if(other_condition)
  //       do this;
  //       else ...
 }
 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
  return xyz;
 }

 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  //All Views Declared Here
  public ViewHolder(View view) {
   super(view);
   //AllViewsDefinedHere
  }
 }
}
```

Another little thing I would like to ask is that I have seen various libraries like FastAdapter which says they simplify the whole adapter work but I couldn't understand how they help. Is there some issue with manual Adapter approach?

Comment: You can follow the MVP approach, create a `BaseViewHolder` and a `BaseAdapter`

Comment: @AyushKhare Can you please provide some Sample Code or helping Link, thnx in advance.

Comment: I have provided the links in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the **Model-View-Presenter** approach for your requirement. Having a `BaseViewHolder` and `BaseAdapter` and different `SecondaryViewHolders` extending `BaseViewHolders` for each viewType.

Since you say layout files cannot be same, `SecondaryViewHolders` will be independent and will contain the respective layout files.

You can read [this](https://medium.com/@ayushkhare/multi-type-recycler-view-a-better-approach-1d9ae4e30f95) to get more details

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/ayushkhare/MultiRecylerView)

Comment: Won't that be the same thing. Having so many different classes although extending. Any benefit?

Comment: This way we can have different view holders for different data types, using different layouts. Your code structure will be more clean